# ¿Cómo puedo leer en un mismo json un campo por fecha y desplegar en el mismo objeto el resultado de 2 o más campos, ejemplo:

Tags: java, android, json, restful

De un json así leído en **java** o **php**

```
{
 "Numero": 1,
 "Kms": 831316,
 "FechaUltVale": "11\/01\/2018",
},
{
 "Numero": 2,
 "Kms": 821316,
 "FechaUltVale": "11\/01\/2018",
},
```

**Volverlo así**

```
{
        "Numero": 1,
        "Kms": 831316,
        "Numero2": 2,
        "Kms2": 821316,
        "FechaUltVale": "11\/01\/2018",
},
```

Para así mostrar la comparación en **android** en un **cardview**

-Ya intente generando 2 arrays con sus respectivos resultados
y los uní así, pero no es lo que requiero
$union = array_combine($resultado, $resultado2);

-También recorrer en un for el array combinado y buscar coincidencias pero tampoco
$resultado=json_encode($rendimientos2);
    $resultado=json_decode($resultado);
    $arraynuevo = array();

```
$Kms2="";

for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){ 

if( isset($resultado[$i]->Unidad) ){
$Unidad=$resultado[$i]->Unidad;
$Kms=$resultado[$i]->Kms;
//echo "Unidad: ".$Unidad." Kms: ".$Kms;
//echo "
//";
}

if( isset($resultado[$i]->Unidad2) ){   
$Unidad2=$resultado[$i]->Unidad2;   
$Kms2=$resultado[$i]->Kms2;
}
```

$arraynuevo["Unidad1"] = $Unidad;
$arraynuevo["Kms"] = $Kms;
$arraynuevo["Unidad2"] = $Unidad2;
$arraynuevo["Kms2"] = $Kms2;

```
$resultado2[] =$arraynuevo;

}
```

echo json_encode($resultado2);

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio rafael!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: Gracias, revisando